# Using another font in page number causes incorrect page numbering in XeLaTeX

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec

In the following code when we use another font for page number, the page number starts from 2 in the first page.  The pages are numbered 2, 3, 4, 5. However, the log message during compilation shows that total *four* pages have been generated.

If the command `\palladio` is removed from the following two lines, the error disappears.

```
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{{\palladio\thepage}}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{{\palladio\thepage}}{}{}
```

(If the page style is changed to `Ruled`, the pages get numbered 1, 3, 4, 5.)

Here is the MWE from a much larger task.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{memoir}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{english}

% Times New Roman used
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}

% Second font for page numbers
\newfontfamily\palladio{URW Palladio L}

\pagestyle{plain}
\makeoddfoot{plain}{}{}{{\palladio\thepage}}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{{\palladio\thepage}}{}{}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\chapter{First}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

I am attaching the output here though it is a bit big.
As you can see, the usage of footers are just the opposite. The
even footer is being used for the odd numbered pages and vice versa.
So, internally, the page numbers are correct.

Moreover, the chapter start page style is *not* plain.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I am using XeLaTeX in Ubuntu.

---

**Update 1**

Output of `{\palladio 0123456789}`.

[image]

$\text{Strange}^\infty$

Comment: I used `Arial` I don't have pallatino and there is no problem. I am in windows 2) the plain style isn't changed by `\makeevenfoot`?

Comment: Can you show the log-file of the MWE?

Comment: I copied the URW Palladio L font file from my Ghostscript distribution; in this case I get “ÿ” in the first page, 1 in the second page and so on. What kind of font file is your copy?

Comment: @egreg This is produced by `fc-list`: `/usr/share/fonts/type1/gsfonts/p052023l.pfb: URW Palladio L:style=Italic`

Comment: Please see my update. Do I need to to vote to close the question? Is it a local issue?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not the font. In fact, I changed font when testing your code because I don't have Palladio, and it still showed your same result. You need to invert the position in the command, because basically it works like:

```
\makeoddfoot{plain}{ <left> }{ <center> }{ <right> }
```

So you need to switch your commands like this:

```
\makeoddfoot{plain}{{\palladio\thepage}}{}{}
\makeevenfoot{plain}{}{}{{\palladio\thepage}}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: this is more strange

Comment: I don't get it. (1) Should not the page number come out where ever I place it?  (2) Why will a font change command change the page number? The page number comes out alright as soon as the font change command is removed.

Comment: @Masroor In my document, even removing `\palladio` from the command will keep the wrong  display of page numbers. So I don't know why in your case there is such a switch, to be honest.

Comment: @Masroor: Sometimes glyphs in a fonts can get wrong, e.g. if there are two versions of the font, but you would see this in the text too, so try out {\palladio 1234}.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer So this is a specific issue with URW Palladio L?

Comment: @Alenanno: I have no idea currently. You are saying you are seeing the problem without it too, so perhaps it is something else.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yeah with `Times`. I don't have that font, but using a different font with the same commands, or removing the font but still switching the commands yields the expected results.